GKE: Unable to get AWS credentials using STS assumeRoleWithWebIdentity
I'm having a service running on Google Kubernetes Engine and would like to access an AWS service using Workforce Identity Federation following this guide
I managed already to get the web Identity Token from my google service account and I also tested with an ubuntu-pod with the aws cli installed that it worked so I am positive that the setup is correct.
However when I try to get the AWS credentials from my java application using the SDK it fails to get them.
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load 
credentials from any of the providers in the chain 
AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), 
EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), 
ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])),
 ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : 
[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings.
 Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or 
system property (aws.accessKeyId)., EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to
 load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via 
environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., 
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable 
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set.,
 ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])):
 Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'default': ProfileFile(sections=[]),
 ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither 
AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment
 variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to load credentials 
from IMDS.]

My code is beneath using software.amazon.awssdk:sts:2.26.0:
try (StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.of(appProperties.getAwsRegion()))
            .build()) {
          AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest request = AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest.builder()
              .roleArn(appProperties.getAwsGoogleRoleArn())
              .roleSessionName(extractSub(idTokenFromMetadataServer))
              .webIdentityToken(idTokenFromMetadataServer)
              .build();
          AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse response = stsClient.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(
              request);
          String accessKey = credentials().accessKeyId();
          String secretKey = response.credentials().secretAccessKey();
        }

The aws region variable is 'eu-north-1'

The solution was very easy. The StsClient tries to first initialize it's own credentials and those follow some default handlers for this. You just need to specify that in this case the stsClient needs to be used as an anonymous user by applying the anonymous credentials provider:
StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(AnonymousCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(Region.of(appProperties.getAwsRegion()))
            .build()

